# WPF Multitouch Issue

Tags: wpf, multi-touch

I am using the following link for multitouch in WPF.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649090%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

I am able to achieve the multitouch effect. It works fine.
 But the problem is, the control in my case (Rectangle) goes out of the window. How can i make the control in my case the rectangle stay inside the window. So when i drag the rectangle it should stop at the border of the window and should not move out of the window. Please provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In your ManipulationDelta event handler you have to call `ManipulationDeltaEventArgs.ReportBoundaryFeedback`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988680(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I had used ManipulationDeltaEventArgs.ReportBoundaryFeedback. It does not seems to be working https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988680(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also now i am not able to get the touch on it. So how do i get the touch and get the event stop at the boundary of the window.

Comment: Also i get the error message that myapplication.exe has stopped working. The touch does not seems to be working now. Please provide some suggestions for it.

Comment: I dont have device vith visual studio and touch screen availlable right now, so maybe later